# Fading Text Colors in Snow Leopard Terminal while scrolling?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, colors

I found some very odd behavior today while using the Terminal (I work in it a lot) that I'd never seen before. I just reformatted my HD and installed Snow Leopard on a clean partition, before using Migration Assistant to replace all my old goodies. I use SIMBL for color adjustments.

While two finger scrolling using my MBPs trackpad, the text in the terminal changes from green to yellow. The text in the direction I am scrolling remains green and fades to yellow. If I scroll slowly, only one line is green before turning yellow immediately. If I scroll quickly, I get a smooth fade from green to yellow.

I've never seen this before, it doesn't happen with the scroll bar, and I didn't see anything on a quick [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=terminal+snow+leopard+color+scroll&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) search. Has anyone ever seen this before or know what causes it?

Comment: This sounds like the phenomenon called 'submarining' caused by slow persistence phosphors on CRT screens, but you're using an LCD, I imagine. Is the screen driver *emulating* the old-fashioned phosphor display, somehow?

Comment: How do you use SIMBL "for color adjustments?"

Comment: @NSD http://bit.ly/3DAv5l SIMBL plugin TerminalColours allows for more control over colors of text. I've used it for years w/o issue (and months with SL with no issues).

Comment: @pavium I wouldn't think so.

Comment: I found that it may have been due to an aborted ColorSync calibration from earlier in the day. I completed the advanced calibration (don't know if the advanced part mattered) and the problem seems to be gone. So now, my 'submarining' is gone and my display looks better than it did before. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you:

1. Tried removing the SIMBL 'plug-in' to see if the error still exists.
2. Seen if the error (colour shifting) occurs in other programs?

If it occurs in other programs you may have a corrupt ColorSync Profile. If it does not check for an update on your SIMBL 'plug-in'.

You can change your ColorSync Profile in the Color tab of the Display Preference Pane.

Comment: I found that it may have been due to an aborted ColorSync calibration from earlier in the day. I completed the advanced calibration (don't know if the advanced part mattered) and the problem seems to be gone. So now, my 'submarining' is gone and my display looks better than it did before. Thanks all.